# How to calculate an array index from a hash

Tags: java, hash

I've seen examples on how to create a hash for a string. Here is one example in Java:

```
private int getHashCode(String text) {
    int hash = 7;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        hash = hash * 31 + text.charAt(i);
    }

    return hash;
}
```

This of course can produce large numbers. If I am storing my strings in an array and I have only say 10 array items, how do I calculate the array index from the hash code? I can of course use a HashMap to do this, but I want to do this as part of learning how indexes are created from hash codes.

Comment: The hash function output is a number between 0...n, the hash itself is the index. However the hash should be transparent for you, you should not access the object by index.If you want a shorter array you should shrink the function codomain

Comment: The hash is not the index. The code above will generate very large values when the text is long. The hash is just one part of getting to the index. I'm still missing the part of going from the hash to the index.

Comment: You can go from the hash to the index if you are using a function with the codomain in the rage of your array. A hash function is a function f:String->[a, b] , in your case a= 0 , b = length-1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the remainder operator (`%`) to map your hash code to an index of an array :

```
int index = obj.getHashCode ("SomeString") % yourArray.length;
```

Of course, you should be able to handle clashes (i.e. situations in which two or more Strings are mapped to the same array index).

`HashMap` handles such potential clashes by storing in each index of the array an entry instance that can point to the next entry that was mapped to that same index (thus forming a linked list).

EDIT:

As was correctly commented below, the `%` operator wouldn't work for negative hash codes. As an alternative, you can use [Math.floorMod](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floorMod-int-int-) (introduced in Java 8) instead :

```
int index = Math.floorMod (obj.getHashCode ("SomeString"), yourArray.length);
```

This is guaranteed to return a non-negative index, regardless of the sign of the hash code.

Or you can take the alternative used in `HashMap` implementation. If the length of your array is always a power of 2, you can use `obj.getHashCode ("SomeString") & (yourArray.length - 1)`.

Comment: Because Java's `%` operator is not sane, this won't work if you have a negative hashcode.

Comment: @khelwood Well, you can easily account for that (for example, by applying the `%` operator on the absolute value of the hash code).

Comment: It's worth noting that when changing the size of the array, the position at which each item should be stored may change.

Comment: @davmac That's a valid point. So Eran's simple solution implies that you cannot use it if you need to resize your array.

Comment: @AndroidDev `HashMap` uses a similar solution. When the array is resized, all the entries must be rehashed (i.e. the array index should be re-calculated for them before they can be added to the new array).

Comment: @AndroidDev you can use it, but you must move the elements within the array when you perform the resize. I don't think there's any real solution which avoids this necessity; I just think that it's worth mentioning to someone who seems interested in the implementation of a hash-based store.

Comment: @Holger Agreed. Edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

from java hashmap implementation

n - > Size of array

**`index = hashCode(key) & (n-1).`**

Comment: Will work only if n is a power of 2